# Parsing a C# string statement and executing it via reflection to get a value

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a utility that can take a C# string like this:

'Utils.ComputeValue('Myval1', 'Myval2');'

And execute the underlying function via reflection and return a value?

I can parse and trigger via reflection myself, but am trying to avoid that.

The idea is also to restrict ability to call functions into one specific namespace... to avoid abuse.

Comment: What "underlying function" ? What problem are you trying to solve? Sounds like something you don't really want nor need to do.

Comment: That isn't built in. There are a number of libraries that add string/expression parsing functionality. Or: there are scripting tools that *are* part of the framework (think IronPython, IronRuby, or you could use Roslyn, etc).

Comment: Have a look into https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples is that going in the direction you are thinking of?